# When I would change a formula, then when the value from that formula will change?

Tags: apex, soql, formula, administration, image-formula

I have a hyptothetical formula (in pseudocode):

- if (XXX_field is empty): return 100
  And I will change it to return 200

1. When should I see changes in that field? (200 instead of 100)
   Only after updating that specific field?
2. If so, is it possible to do an "artificial" update only so that we can have that value updated?

Comment: The values of the formula fields are dynamically loaded/calculated each time you view a record. From the moment you change the formula, you will see the new value on all existing records.

Answer (score 2):

Formula fields do not have their values stored, they are calculated on-demand.

Every time you query a record in Apex or view a record in a web browser, the formula fields are re-calculated. So there is nothing you need to do to update the formula results other than modifying the formula and then refreshing a record page.